# How can I achieve a complicated CSS layout?

Tags: html, css

I have a page [here](http://technobotts.info/documentation/documentation.php?DataProcessing). There is a contents panel, and a content panel. I would like to center the content, and push the contents panel to the top right corner. This behaviour already works.

**However**, the layout does not work as I would like when the page is shrunk. Ideally, the content would be pushed to the right side of the screen, and a `5px` gap maintained between the content and the contents. At present, however, the contents just overlaps the content, which isn't really what I want.

Is such a layout possible, without resorting to javascript?

**Edit:** You may notice a scrollbar at the edge of the page. That scroll-bar is **not** the `body`'s scrollbar, but `div#main`'s, the reason being that I don't want the contents to scroll with the page.

Answer (score 3):

i believe it is achievable using the **min-width** property on your container.  expect problems with ie6 though.  it doesn't recognize the min-width declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Is not just min-width. I managed to achieve the layout by doing the following:

For `#main` add (adjust the values to fit your needs):

- min-width: 950px;

For `#contents` add:

- float: right;
- margin-top: 5px;
- margin-right: 20px;

For `#contents ol` remove:

- position
- right
- top

Comment: +1 seems to work. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b62tA/) for those who want try it out.

Comment: Oops. Looks like I forgot to mention that the contents should _not_ scroll. The `position: absolute` was a cross-browser alternative to position: fixed. @Matt: +1 for the fiddle

Comment: Maybe is too late now to think clearly but I don't think a fixed position can be obtained (without javascript) when using float... Why don't you move contents on the left side and use min-width combined with an absolute position?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at YUI CSS Grid layout to achieve similar issues in the future.  See http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/